# Display selected checkboxes visually to user in separate div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a multi select dropdown which I want a `div` to display each selected `checkbox` (from my `array`) which displays like something below

[image]

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I'm sure I have seen this being used before but I can't find it anywhere or even know how to create the design. I can't even think of the name of thing I'm wanting.

Comment: Firstly this question is too broad for SO. Secondly, checkout Select2 when applied to a `<select multiple>`: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes it is broad as i cant rem the naming its given

Comment: Remembering the name of the control wouldn't make it any less broad. It's a 'tag well', by the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see this code.

Your dropdown:

```
<select class="custom-select" multiple>
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option selected value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option selected value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option selected value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Your div:

```
<div style="border-style: solid;">
  <div class="show-selected">Option 1</div>
  <div class="show-selected">Option 2</div>
  <div class="show-selected">Option 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.show-selected {
  font-size:500
}
```

This should hopefully get this ticket cleared off your backlog/tfs/jira/git.